# Wronskian based on DE Solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

Suppose you have two solutions of: 
$$
y''+\cos(t)y'+3(\ln(|t|))y=0
$$ on the interval $~t > 0~$. What can you say about their Wronskian?

All that I can think to say is that the Wronskian would just be nonzero (assuming the solutions are nonlinear.)

Is there anything else that I may add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Abel's formula:
$$W = Ce^{-\sin(x)}$$